# many ssh connections being repeatedly opened by the same user on linux server

Tags: linux, ssh

ps aux gives me something like this:

```
root     30800  0.0  0.3 101792  6360 ?        Ss   17:23   0:00 sshd: user_name [priv]
user_na+ 30812  0.0  0.1 101792  3680 ?        S    17:23   0:00 sshd: user_name
root     30819  0.0  0.3 101792  6304 ?        Ss   17:01   0:00 sshd: user_name [priv]
root     30866  0.0  0.3 101792  6420 ?        Ss   17:23   0:00 sshd: user_name [priv]
user_na+ 30868  0.0  0.1 101792  3720 ?        S    17:23   0:00 sshd: user_name
root     30919  0.0  0.3 101792  6312 ?        Ss   17:23   0:00 sshd: user_name [priv]
user_na+ 30921  0.0  0.1 101792  3680 ?        S    17:23   0:00 sshd: user_name
root     30964  0.0  0.3 101792  6356 ?        Ss   17:23   0:00 sshd: user_name [priv]
user_na+ 30966  0.0  0.1 101792  3700 ?        S    17:24   0:00 sshd: user_name
user_na+ 30983  0.0  0.1 101792  3560 ?        S    17:01   0:00 sshd: user_name
root     31065  0.0  0.3 101792  6392 ?        Ss   17:24   0:00 sshd: user_name [priv]
user_na+ 31069  0.0  0.1 101792  3620 ?        S    17:24   0:00 sshd: user_name
root     31130  0.0  0.3 101792  6416 ?        Ss   17:24   0:00 sshd: user_name [priv]
user_na+ 31134  0.0  0.1 101792  3688 ?        S    17:24   0:00 sshd: user_name
root     31169  0.0  0.3 101792  6308 ?        Ss   17:24   0:00 sshd: user_name [priv]
user_na+ 31175  0.0  0.1 101792  3492 ?        S    17:24   0:00 sshd: user_name
root     31212  0.0  0.3 101792  6452 ?        Ss   17:24   0:00 sshd: user_name [priv]
user_na+ 31216  0.0  0.1 101792  3772 ?        S    17:24   0:00 sshd: user_name
root     31269  0.0  0.3 101792  6292 ?        Ss   17:24   0:00 sshd: user_name [priv]
```

This is just a shortened list, there are around 150 lines of this.

after I tried killing them new sshd connections were being spawned.

User "user_name" is disabled, if I do cat /etc/passwd | grep user_name, I get this:

```
user_name:x:1521:1521::/home/user_name:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Is someone trying to break in here or how can I find out what is going on here?

Comment: What is `user_name`? Is it an account that you know / expect to be in use? What is the remote IP? Do you recognise it? What does `tail -n 150 /var/log/auth.log` say? Is the session running anything?

Comment: Strange... If you have root permissions, you could add a DenyUsers line in sshd_config (and restart sshd), in order to prevent new access.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `user_name` has a `~user_name/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, which if you allow key-based logins in your `sshd_config`, can also bypass password-based restrictions on logins depending upon your authentication setup.  For example, `pam` based systems often have a separate `ssh` connection configuration (see `/etc/pam.d/sshd`).  Also, just because the login shell of `user_name` is `/usr/sbin/nologin` does not mean that `ssh` connections cannot be made, if the client is specifying a command to be run as part of the connection.

As for if you are the subject of an attack, I cannot say.  You can see what other processes are owned by that user id.